# Problems using Microsoft assemblies in Mono project

Tags: c#, mono, assemblies

I want to build a project with mono which uses Microsoft.Build names.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;
```

The whole file is available [here](https://github.com/golergka/MonoSublimeLogger/blob/master/LoggerImpl.cs).

However, I get these errors:

```
$ mcs LoggerImpl.cs
LoggerImpl.cs(4,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Build' does not exist in the namespace `Microsoft'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
LoggerImpl.cs(5,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Build' does not exist in the namespace `Microsoft'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
LoggerImpl.cs(15,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IEventSource' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
LoggerImpl.cs(28,44): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ProjectStartedEventArgs' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
LoggerImpl.cs(36,43): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `BuildFinishedEventArgs' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
LoggerImpl.cs(52,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `BuildErrorEventArgs' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
LoggerImpl.cs(62,43): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `BuildWarningEventArgs' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
Compilation failed: 7 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Same with smcs. This is strange, because gacutil lists Microsoft.Build as an installed assembly:

```
$gacutil -l Microsoft.Build
The following assemblies are installed into the GAC:
Microsoft.Build, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Number of items = 1
```

And even Microsoft.Build.Framework (which is also used) is installed:

```
$ gacutil -l Microsoft.Build.Framework
The following assemblies are installed into the GAC:
Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Number of items = 3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Quote: Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: I think that the e.g. `Microsoft.Build.Framework` is not running under Mono. Please check all your assemblies with MoMA: http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft.Build.dll is there, but you need to reference it:

```
mcs LoggerImpl.cs -r:Microsoft.Build.dll
```